# Map projection which is most accurate in the (global) calculation of "Poles of Inaccessibility"

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, point, vector, coordinates

I would like to calculate the "Pole of Inaccessibility" in QGIS for several polygons. The polygons (administrative boundaries of countries) are globally distributed.

When calculating in different (global) projected coordinate systems (e.g. Mercator (Conformal), Mollweide (Equal-area), Winkel Tripel (Compromise)), I noticed that there are clear differences in the positions of the newly calculated points.

Since different map projections try to preserve different metric properties, this was to be expected.

Which metric property of a projection (area, length, angle) has the greatest influence on the accuracy of the (global) calculation of the "Pole of Inaccessibility"?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. A bullet list of questions is a quick way to generate closure votes. Please [Edit] the Question to contain your most pressing question (preferably one that is not *opinion-based*, since subjective questions are also off-topic here).

Comment: @Vince Sorry; thank you for the advice. I have adjusted the question accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is still not specific enough. Projection selection is a judgement call, and it differs by the area and the task. Given the variability of size in "all countries of the world" you have a nearly intractable task here.

Comment: Unfortunately, you will have to use a few different map projections and reference-ellipsoids to calculate the "pole of inaccessibility" for all countries in the world. There are different suitable reference-ellipsoids and map projections for different regions of the world.

Comment: @Vince Okay, I have adjusted the question again.

Comment: @KVO Using different map projections and reference ellipsoids depending on the country would certainly be the most accurate. However, this would involve many additional steps (as far as I can estimate). I would like to do the calculation in one step (i.e. in one map projection). The accuracy of a suitable global projection would be sufficient for me.